# JSON Array and CoreData in populating TableView

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, core-data

Sorry for inconvenience, I am iOS-Beginner and have a problem...

I have a JSON, CoreData and TableView, JSON fetched from web and saving in Documents-Folder. After that, some values from JSON saves in CoreData and TableView must be populated with it. F.E. we take an event_title..

I have a controller:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import CoreData

class QuestListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

let eventscd = [Events]()

@IBOutlet weak var questsTabBarItem: UITabBarItem!

var questCode : String = ""

var numberofcells:Int = 0

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var numbers:[String] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Events", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)

    let events = Events(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

    var error: NSError?
    var jsonError:NSError?
    let jsonBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
    let jsonFolder = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]as! String
    let jsonPath = jsonFolder.stringByAppendingPathComponent("\(self.questCode).json")

    if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile:jsonPath, options:NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingUncached, error:&jsonError) {

        let stringData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        let jsonDict : NSDictionary? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &jsonError) as? NSDictionary

        if let err = jsonError {
            println("error parsing json")
        }

        if let jsonDictionary = jsonDict {
            println("json parsed successfully")

            let json_data = JSON(jsonDictionary).arrayValue

            let id = jsonDictionary["id"]!.stringValue
            let version: AnyObject = jsonDictionary["version"]!
            let title: AnyObject = jsonDictionary["title"]!
            let description: AnyObject = jsonDictionary["description"]!
            let events_json = jsonDictionary["events"] as! NSArray
            let eventNumber: NSNumber = jsonDictionary["events"]!.count as NSNumber
            self.numberofcells = events_json.count

        }

    }


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
// MARK: - Table view data source
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    let row = indexPath.row

}

// MARK: - Set number of rows
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.numberofcells
}

// MARK: - Create cell
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    cell.backgroundView = UIView.new()
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = UIView.new()

    var imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(10, 10, cell.frame.width - 0.3, cell.frame.height - 0.3))
    let image = UIImage(named: "event_list_cell.png")
    imageView.image = image
    cell.backgroundView = UIView()
    cell.backgroundView!.addSubview(imageView)
    var row = indexPath.row
    let eventsc = eventscd[indexPath.row]  /////HERE IS FATAL BREAKPOINT

//        cell.textLabel?.text = eventTable[row] as? String
    cell.textLabel?.text = eventsc.valueForKey("event_title")![row] as? String

    return cell
}

}
```

A class for Events:
    import Foundation
    import CoreData

```
@objc(Events) class Events: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var title: String
    @NSManaged var event_title: String

}
```

And a CoreMap:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/izQp9.png

And have an error:

```
On line with "let eventsc = eventscd[indexPath.row]" in Controller
Output: "fatal error: Array index out of range"
```

Where I am wrong?

Comment: Where do you put the values into `eventscd`?

Comment: where is the array `eventscd` populated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because in the `viewDidLoad` you are setting the `numberOfCells` to a value > 0. But you don't have anything in `eventscd`. That is why when trying to read a value from `eventscd`, you get an index out of range error.

Ideally the number of rows returned should be `eventscd.count` and `eventscd` should be populated before loading the table contents (or the table reloaded once you get data and add values to `eventscd`)

Comment: I got about `eventscd` but almost not everything about what you said) How should I represent TableCells? With another var/let or transform somehow the `eventscd`?

Comment: You need to add data to `eventscd` from wherever you are getting this data from. if events_json has the data, use that to populate eventscd. Or if you have to get the data from CoreData, do that.

Answer (score 0):

You should populate your table view with a `NSFetchedResultsController`. Look at the Xcode template (New Project -> Master-Detail -> check "Use Core Data") and examine the master controller.

That is so much better (performance, memory, maintainability) than using an array.

Comment: It's too hard for me now to understand other's code) Trying to write by my own with Documentation... I need to populate it with event_title, i have it in json Events[ [....,title1,....],[....,title3,....],[....,title3,....]  ]

Comment: Bad idea. Ignore Apple's reference implementation at your own peril.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I just need these cells to show "event_title"